# Query not giving solution in DAO class

Tags: java, postgresql, hibernate, jpql

when i run my query in database visualizer its working perfectly, but i think there are some issues in syntax when i convert it in my DAO class method.

I want to get whole data against the name provided

In Visualizer:

```
SELECT first_name,last_name,nic,phone,email FROM x_hr_user where (first_name = 'Irum');
```

Now in Dao

```
public List<XHrUser> findXHrUserByNameInTable() 
{
String name ="Irum"; 
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT xHrNewUserObj.firstName,xHrNewUserObj.lastName, xHrNewUserObj.nic, xHrNewUserObj.phone, xHrNewUserObj.emil FROM XHrUser xHrNewUserObj where (xHrNewUserObj.firstName) = (name)");

List<XHrUser> list = query.getResultList();
return list;

}
```

Instead of showing single row, it displays whole data Table
Thank you

Comment: Name is not a variable here it is a column name in where statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current query is not valid JPQL.  It appears that you intended to insert the raw `name` string into your query, which could be done via a native query, but certainly is not desirable.  Instead, use a named parameter in your JPQL query and then bind `name` to it.

```
String name = "Irum";
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT x FROM XHrUser WHERE x.firstName = :name")
    .setParameter("name", name);

List<XhrUser> list = query.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write query as below. where : is used for variable

```
Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT xHrNewUserObj.firstName,xHrNewUserObj.lastName, xHrNewUserObj.nic, xHrNewUserObj.phone, xHrNewUserObj.emil FROM XHrUser xHrNewUserObj where (xHrNewUserObj.firstName) = :name");
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is even valid JPQL, but even if it runs, it misses the point.  A JPQL query returns an entity, which maps to a class, so you get back _all_ the fields of the `XHrUser` object.